# Oracle Trigger does not execute - INSTR function issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a trigger to detect when a user name includes an illegal string (such as obscenities).

I have two small tables: Player and IllegalWords, where IllegalWords contains the words against which the user names will be checked.

I tested the code on www.sqlfiddle.com, using Oracle version 11g R2.

The trigger works when the user name matches an illegal word (including the instances where the letters casing, i.e. small caps / large caps, is different). However, it fails when the illegal word is a sub-string of the user name. For example, it fails to detect that sad clown contains clown.

I do not understand why, since I used the function INSTR.

Could anyone help me understand?

Thank you,

LC

```
CREATE TABLE Player (
    PlayerID INT,
    UserName CHAR(100),
    IsLocked CHAR(1) DEFAULT 0
)/

CREATE TABLE IllegalWords
(
    Word CHAR(100)
)/


INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (1, 'John Doe', 0)/

INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (2, 'Paris Hilton', 0)/

INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (3, 'Krusty', 0)/

INSERT INTO Player
VALUES (4, 'Pierrot', 0)/

INSERT INTO IllegalWords
VALUES ('clown')/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CheckIllegalName
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF UserName ON Player
BEGIN
    FOR r1 in (SELECT UserName FROM Player)
    LOOP
        FOR r2 in (SELECT Word FROM IllegalWords)
        LOOP
            IF (INSTR(LOWER(r1.UserName), LOWER(r2.Word)) != 0) THEN
                UPDATE Player SET IsLocked = 1 WHERE UserName = r1.UserName;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END CheckIllegalName;
/

UPDATE Player
SET UserName = 'clown'
WHERE PlayerID = 1/

UPDATE Player
SET UserName = 'Clown'
WHERE PlayerID = 2/


UPDATE Player
SET UserName = 'sadclown'
WHERE PlayerID = 3/

UPDATE Player
SET UserName = 'clown_is_sad'
WHERE PlayerID = 4/

SELECT * FROM Player/
```

Result:

```
PLAYERID, USERNAME, ISLOCKED
1, clown, 1
2, Clown, 1
3, sadclown, 0
4, clown_is_sad, 0
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in sqlfiddle. Have you tried this code on an actual Oracle database?

Comment: I did try the same code on an actual database (version 9.2) and the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the data-type of your Word:

```
CREATE TABLE IllegalWords
(
    Word CHAR(100)
)/
```

I'm not sure why, because the doc say `CHAR` should work, but if I chance the Datatype to VARCHAR2 it works.

Comment: Brilliant! It works. I would never have found this by myself. I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Icazarre: CHAR fields are automatically blank-filled on the right to the full width of the field. VARCHAR2 only stores the characters given. So when 'Krusty' is stored in a CHAR(20), "Krusty"+14 blanks is what's recorded in the field. The same value stored in a VARCHAR2(20) field is "Krusty" without blank padding. [SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc896/2). [Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1821). In general, use VARCHAR2 - it'll save you a lot of grief and sleepless nights. Share and enjoy.